# Integration of a rational function from +/- infinity

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{a+x}{b^2 + (a+x)^2}\frac{1}{1+c(a-x)^2}}dx$$

where $\{a, b, c\}\in \mathbb{R}$. I have looked in a table of integrals for rational functions, but with no luck. Is there a smart trick I can utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use partial fraction to write the integral as

$$ {\frac{a+x}{b^2 + (a+x)^2}\frac{1}{1+c(a-x)^2}} = \frac{A+Bx}{b^2 + (a+x)^2} + \frac{C+D x}{1+c(a-x)^2}, $$

then you can write it as

$$ \frac{A}{b^2 + (a+x)^2} + \frac{C}{1+c(a-x)^2} + \frac{Bx}{b^2 + (a+x)^2} + \frac{D x}{1+c(a-x)^2}, $$

and finally make the change of variables $x-a=t$ and $x+a=t$ and things will be easy. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390456/laplace-transform-int-0-infty-frac-sin4-xx3-dx/390475#390475) for similar techniques and read the comments under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Potential Hint:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{a}{(b^2 + (a+x)^2)(1+c(a-x)^2)}} - {\frac{x}{(b^2 + (a+x)^2)(1+c(a-x)^2)}}dx$$

The first part can be solved using a chain rule like method. The second half can be solved using integration by parts with $u = x$ i.e $u\prime = 1$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to simplify it by putting the term under the integral in the following manner:
$$\frac{a+x}{b^2 + (a+x)^2}\frac{1}{1+c(a-x)^2}=\frac{\alpha +x}{\beta  (c (x-a)^2+1)}-\frac{\gamma }{\delta +x}$$
with $$\alpha =\frac{4 a^2 c+a b^2 c+1}{b^2 c}$$
$$\beta =\frac{4 a^2 c+4 a b^2 c+b^4 c+1}{b^2 c}$$
$$\gamma =\frac{b^2}{4 a^2 c+4 a b^2 c+b^4 c+1}$$
$$\delta =a+b^2$$
which are just constants.
So
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{a+x}{b^2 + (a+x)^2}\frac{1}{1+c(a-x)^2}}dx=\frac{\alpha}{\beta c}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ (x-a)^2+\frac{1}{c}}dx&+&\\+\frac{1}{\beta c}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{ (x-a)^2+\frac{1}{c}}dx &-&\\-\gamma\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\delta +x}dx
\end{eqnarray*}
$$