# Evaluating integration with Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am taking a differential equation class and for Laplace transformations and I have to find $$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin t}{t}dt.$$

How can I do that?

Comment: Here is the [general technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390456/laplace-transform-int-0-infty-frac-sin4-xx3-dx/390475#390475).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx=\int_0^\infty F(s) \, ds$$ (memorize it). Now setting $f(x)=\sin x$ and $\mathcal{L}\{\sin x\}=\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$, we have $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s^2+1} \, ds=\arctan s\Big|_0^\infty =\pi/2$$

Comment: tnx, but i didn't know the formula

Comment: we were only given L{f(t)/t} = integral F(s) ds from 0 to infinity

Comment: could you please mention from where you took ∫∞0f(x)/xdx=∫∞0F(s)ds

Comment: @madU: Theorem: If $\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\}=F(s)$ and if the L.T of $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists then we have the above formula.

Comment: ok, i still didn't get it completely, but tnx a lot
i'll try to go through it and understand the theorem you mentioned

Comment: @madU: Follow [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency)

Comment: $+1$ for my dear friend!

Comment: The integral $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ converges conditionally, so the usual Fubini's theorem doesn't justify the change in order of integration that gives you the identity that this answer tells the reader to memorize.  Instead, one has to write $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^a \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$, then apply Fubini's theorem, and then take the limit as $a\to\infty$ only after that.  So there are some complications.

Comment: tnx for all, finally i got it