# How find this integral limit

Tags: integration, limits

> Find this limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\left(\dfrac{\sin{(nx)}}{\sin{x}}\right)^4dx}{n^2}.$$

This problem is post my teacher(tian275461, he is very popular in China), and he told me this problem answer is $\ln{2}$, but I can't prove it. Thank you.

Comment: Can we see tian275461 page or is he here likes @tian275461 ?.

Comment: A numerical calculation yields values close to
${\large \ln\left(2\right)}$.

Answer (score 7):

I can assure your integral equals $$\tag 1 \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4 t}{t^3}dt$$ But I have no proof now. Can you show this equals $\log 2$? Numerically, it checks out.

A heuristical argument for $(1)$ would be replacing $\sin x$ with $x$, the noting that you get $$\int\limits_0^{\pi /2} {nx{{\left( {\frac{{\sin nx}}{{nx}}} \right)}^4}d\left( {nx} \right) \to \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{{\sin }^4}t}}{{{t^3}}}dt} } $$

A way to strengthen this argument would be to show that your integral vanishes over any interval $[\delta,\pi/2]$ as $n\to\infty$; and then working locally in $[0,\delta]$ for some small $\delta>0$ to make precise claims. Of course $\delta n\to+\infty$ so $(1)$ still holds.

Comment: The application of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma seems to be non-trivial here. Since this is the crux of the problem and you glossed over this point, can you clarify it a little further?

Comment: @pre-kidney You're right. It is non-trivial. I am under the weather now, and it is late, so I don't really have the time nor the energy to work things out. I'll try to look at this some time later.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff   Maple tells $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^4 t}{t^3}dt = \ln 2$. So I think there is some way to prove it by hand.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Actually, you have proved it in the second way. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

With the substitution $y = nx$, we have
\begin{align}
I_n &= \int_0^{n\pi/2} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3} \left(\frac{\frac{y}{n}}{\sin \frac{y}{n}}\right)^4 \mathrm{d} y \\
&= \underbrace{\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3} \left(\frac{\frac{y}{n}}{\sin \frac{y}{n}}\right)^4 \mathrm{d} y}_{I_{n,1}} + 
\underbrace{\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{n\pi/2} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3} \left(\frac{\frac{y}{n}}{\sin \frac{y}{n}}\right)^4 \mathrm{d} y}_{I_{n,2}}.
\end{align}

Since $u \mapsto \frac{u}{\sin u}$ is increasing on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, we have
$$1 \le \left(\frac{\frac{y}{n}}{\sin \frac{y}{n}}\right)^4 \le \left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^4,
\ \forall 0 < y \le \sqrt{n}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3}\mathrm{d} y \le I_{n,1} \le \left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)^4 \int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3} \mathrm{d} y.$$
By the squeeze theorem, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n,1} = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^4 y}{y^3}\mathrm{d} y = \ln 2$
(see e.g. [Laplace transform:$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^4 x}{x^3} \, dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390456/laplace-transform-int-0-infty-frac-sin4-xx3-dx)).

Also, we have
$$I_{n,2} \le \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{n\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^3} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^4 \mathrm{d} y$$
and thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_{n,2} = 0$.

Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = \ln 2$.

Comment: Cool! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. But I do not have a simple proof of the integral.