# Parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $\mu: [x,y]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a parametrized curve in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mu(x)=x_1$ and $\mu(y) = y_1$. Show that
>   for any constant vector $v$ where $\lVert  v \rVert=1$ then: $$(y_1-x_1) \dot\ v =
>  \int^y_x \mu'(t) \dot\ v \ dt \le \int^y_x \lVert\mu'(t)\rVert dt.$$ Using
>   this show that $$\lVert\mu(y)-\mu(x)\rVert\le \int^y_x \lVert\mu'(t)\rVert dt.
> $$

How can I prove this?

For the first part I know that I must use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I don't know how to apply it here. The second part is telling me the distance (or length) between $x_1$ and $y_1$ is less than the length (arc length) of $\mu$?

Comment: Use `\lVert` and `\rVert` for a nicer looking $\lVert x\lVert$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, Cauchy-Schwarz tells us that

$$\mu'(t) \cdot v \leq |\mu'(t) \cdot v| \leq ||\mu'(t)|| \cdot||v|| = ||\mu'(t)||$$

Since $||v|| =1$. Applying integrals, we get

$$ (y_1 - x_1) \cdot v = \int_{x}^{y} \mu'(t) \cdot v \leq \int_{x}^{y} ||\mu'(t)||$$

For the second part, the hint above is good. If you cannot figure it out, the solutions is below (highlight to see the math):

> Note that you can take the absolute value of both sides and preserve the inequality,  since the right-hand side is already positive. But

$$\color{white}{ ||(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v|| = ||(y_1 - x_1)|| \cdot ||v|| \cdot \cos \theta }$$

> So choose a unit length $v$ for which $\cos \theta = 1$

Comment: Why spoil another user's answer, which guides the OP rather than spoon-feeding with a full solution? It is true one is free to answer what one seems fit, but for homework problems like this, and with an already hinting answer, why give it away?

Comment: The OP already said that he needed to use Cauchy-Schwarz, so I did not see the benefit in any hint repeating that fact. You are correct, though, that I should not have expounded upon the second hint. Let me hide that now.

Comment: Use `\lVert` and `\rVert` for a nicer looking $\lVert x\lVert$.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Thank you! I understand clearly now how to do part 1. But for part 2 I am not so sure how you got that?

Comment: @Lays what exactly are you unsure about?

Comment: I understand if I take absolute values it will still preserve angles but why introduce $v$?

Comment: The proof above takes advantage of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, so you introduce $v$ because Cauchy-Schwarz involves the dot product of two different vectors. Once you get the first inequality, you want to replace the left-hand side with $||\mu(y) - \mu(x)||$, which requires you to take the absolute value of $(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v$, and then make a clever choice of $v$ that gives equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: So if I take the absolute value for $(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v$ then I will get $||\mu(y) - \mu(x)|| = ||\mu (t)||\cdot v$ then if I choose $v = \frac{\mu(a) - \mu(b)}{||\mu(a) - \mu(b)||}$ is that correct?

Comment: What you mean to say is: the absolute value of $(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v = \lvert y_1 - x_1 \rvert \lvert v \rvert \cos \theta$. Then if we choose the $v$ you have defined (assuming $x_1 \neq y_1$), then the norm of $v$ is $1$, and $\cos \theta$ will also be $1$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I am troubling, but just to make sure I follow you. 

We start with $(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v$ which by definition equals $ \lvert y_1 - x_1 \rvert \lvert v \rvert \cos \theta$. Now if we take $v = \frac{\mu(a) - \mu(b)}{||\mu(a) - \mu(b)||}$ where $a \ne b$ how can I construct it to complete the proof that $\lVert\mu(y)-\mu(x)\rVert\le \int^y_x \lVert\mu'(t)\rVert dt.$?

Comment: You mean the absolute value of $(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v$ equals that. If you take $v$ as above, then $|y_1 - x_1| |v| \cos \theta = |y_1 - x_1|$. Then simply observe that $|(y_1 - x_1) \cdot v| \leq \int_{x}^{y} |\mu'(t)|$ from part (1).

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The first is Cauchy-Schwarz: Just integrate. For the second, pick the right unit vector $v$.

Comment: [Need back up! =)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482583/how-find-this-integral-limt/482602#482602)

Comment: Yeah, thanks :) I make indenumerably many typing errors on the iPad :( And yet again someone cannot resist writing out every detail when it would be better for the OP to think a bit.