# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin ax-a \sin x}{x^3(x^2+1)} \ dx$ using contour integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How would you compute the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin ax-a\sin x}{x^3(x^2+1)} \ dx ?$$
We will integrate along two circular contours and a striaghtline section between them.(Half donut shape) In the solution my professor give, it stated consider the function $$g(z)=\frac{-1+a+e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}$$ instead of $$f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}$$ because $g$ has simple poles at the real lines. However, the result when we calculate the residue at $i$ is different. I checked the answer using Wolfram, the calculation using $g$ is the correct answer. Can someone explain why?

Comment: So which one should you use to compute the integral $g$? but that is not the same function as our original integral.

Comment: What I stated previously was not correct. I was looking at just a particular value of $a$.   In the first case, $\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{\pi}^{0} g(re^{it}) \  ir e^{it} dt = -\pi i \ \text{Res}[g(z),0]$ since $g(z)$ has a simple pole at the origin. But it can also be shown by expanding $f(z)$ in a Laurent series at the origin and integrating termwise that $\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{\pi}^{0} f(re^{it}) \  ir e^{it} dt = - \pi i \ \text{Res} [f(z),0] $ even though $f(z)$ has a pole of order $3$ at the origin. And $$\text{Im} \ g(x) = \text{Im} \ f(x) = \frac{\sin (ax) - a \sin(x)}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)}.$$

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to expand on my comment about why we can consider the function $$ f(z) = \frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)} \  , \  a >0$$ and that half-donut-shaped contour even though $f(z)$ has a pole of order $3$ at the origin.

Assume that a function $h(z)$ has a Laurent expansion at $z=z_{0}$ of the form $$ \sum_{k=-n}^{-1} a_{2k+1} (z-z_{0})^{2k+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}(z-z_{0})^{k}. $$

And let $C_{r}$ be a semicircle centered at $z=z_{0}$ of radius $r$.

Then $$\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{C_{r}}h(z) \ dz = - i \pi \ \text{Res}[f(z),z_{0}] $$ if $C_{r}$ is traversed clockwise.

For a proof see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459701/integrating-around-a-pole), particularly Daniel Fischer's first comment.

Now if we expand $ \displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}$ in a Laurent series at the origin (as M.N.C.E. did in the other answer) we get $$f(z) = \frac{1-a}{z^{3}} + \frac{-a^{2}+3a-2}{2z} + \mathcal{O}(1). $$

So the above lemma is applicable.

Then integrating around that half-donut-shaped contour and applying both the above lemma and Jordan's lemma,

$$\begin{align} \text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iax}-ae^{ix}}{x^{3}(1+x^{2})} \ dx - i \pi \left(\frac{-a^{2}+3a-2}{2} \right)  &= 2 \pi i \ \text{Res}[f(z), i] \\ &= 2 \pi i \ \lim_{z \to i} \frac{e^{iaz} - a e^{iz}}{z^{3}(z+i)} \\ &= \pi i \left(e^{-a}-ae^{-1} \right). \end{align}$$

And equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)-a \sin(x)}{x^{3}(1+x^{2})} \ dx = \pi \left(e^{-a}-ae^{-1} - \frac{a^{2}-3a+2}{2} \right)$$

which agrees with M.N.C.E.'s answer.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
&\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)-a\sin{x}}{x^3(1+x^2)}dx\\
=& \, \, \frac{1}{2i}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{iax}-ae^{ix}}{(x-i\epsilon)^3(1+x^2)}dx-\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{e^{-iax}-ae^{-ix}}{(x-i\epsilon)^3(1+x^2)}dx\right)\tag1\\
=& \, \,\pi\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i\epsilon}\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{(z-i\epsilon)^3(1+z^2)}+\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{(z-i\epsilon)^3(1+z^2)}\color{red}{+}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i}\frac{e^{-iaz}-ae^{-iz}}{(z-i\epsilon)^3(1+z^2)}\right)\tag2\\
=& \, \,\pi\left(-\frac{a^2-3a+2}{2}+\frac{e^{-a}-ae^{-1}}{2}+\frac{e^{-a}-ae^{-1}}{2}\right)\tag3\\
=& \, \,\pi\left(e^{-a}-ae^{-1}-\frac{a^2-3a+2}{2}\right)
\end{align}

**Explanation:**

$(1)$: Moved the pole into the upper half plane and expanded $\sin$ in terms of complex exponentials. 
$(2)$: Applied the residue theorem. For the first integral in $(1)$, close the contour along the upper half of $|z|=R$, hence picking up the residues at $z=i\epsilon$ and $z=i$. For the second integral in $(1)$, close the contour along the lower half of $|z|=R$, hence picking up the residue at $z=-i$. By Jordan's lemma, the integral along both arcs vanishes. 
$(3)$: Applied the limit and computed the residues. To evaluate the residue at $z=0$,
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(1+z^2)}
&=[z^2]\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{1+z^2}\\
&=[z^2]\left(1-a-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-a)z^2+\mathcal{O}(z^3)\right)\left(1-z^2+\mathcal{O}(z^4)\right)\\
&=a-1-\frac{1}{2}(a^2-a)\\
&=-\frac{a^2-3a+2}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

The reason why $g$ gives the correct answer is that
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(ax)-a\sin(x)&=\frac1{2i}\left(\vphantom{\frac1{2i}}\left[e^{iax}-e^{-iax}\right]-\left[ae^{ix}-ae^{-ix}\right]\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\vphantom{\frac1{2i}}\left[e^{iax}-ae^{ix}\right]-\left[e^{-iax}-ae^{-ix}\right]\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(\vphantom{\frac1{2i}}\left[\color{#0000FF}{-1+a}+e^{iax}-ae^{ix}\right]-\left[\color{#0000FF}{-1+a}+e^{-iax}-ae^{-ix}\right]\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
In fact, we cannot perform the integral using $f$ and the half-doughnut contour without showing that the $\frac1{z^2}$ term of $f(z)$ is $0$. Expanding, we get
$$
\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\sim\frac{1-a}{z^3}-\frac{a^2-3z+2}{2z}-i\frac{a^3-a}6+O(z)
$$
Furthermore, we need to show that for the small semi-circle $\gamma=re^{i[0,\pi]}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^3}
&=\left[-\frac1{2z^2}\right]_{+r}^{-r}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
Thus, as RandomVariable has noted previously, we can do the integral either with or without the addition of $-1+a$, but with the $-1+a$, we only have to deal with simple poles.

---

Regarding the change in the residues at $i$ and $-i$, those changes are cancelled by the change in the residue at $0$. In fact,
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{-1+a}{z^3(z^2+1)}&=(1-a)\\
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\frac{-1+a}{z^3(z^2+1)}&=-\frac{1-a}2\\
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i}\frac{-1+a}{z^3(z^2+1)}&=-\frac{1-a}2
\end{align}
$$

---

However, by moving the contour away from the singularities things become simpler.

Since $\dfrac{\sin(az)-a\sin(z)}{z^3(z^2+1)}$ is bounded in the rectangle
$$
[-R,R]\cup R+[0,i/2]\cup[R,-R]+i/2\cup-R+[i/2,0]
$$
we get that all singularities are removable. Therefore,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)-a\sin(x)}{x^3(x^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{-\infty+i/2}^{\infty+i/2}\frac{\sin(az)-a\sin(z)}{z^3(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z
$$
Using the contours
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma_+&=[-R,R]+i/2\cup Re^{i[0,\pi]}+i/2\\
\gamma_-&=[-R,R]+i/2\cup Re^{-i[0,\pi]}+i/2
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma_+$ circles the singularity at $i$ counterclockwise and $\gamma_-$ circles the singularities at $0$ and $-i$ clockwise, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)-a\sin(x)}{x^3(x^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{2i}\int_{\gamma_+}\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z
-\frac1{2i}\int_{\gamma_-}\frac{e^{-iaz}-ae^{-iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\pi\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\left[\frac{e^{iaz}-ae^{iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\right]\\
&+\pi\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left[\frac{e^{-iaz}-ae^{-iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\right]
+\pi\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-i}\left[\frac{e^{-iaz}-ae^{-iz}}{z^3(z^2+1)}\right]\\
&=\pi\left[\frac{e^{-a}-ae^{-1}}2\right]\\
&+\pi\left[-\frac{a^2-3a+2}2\right]+\pi\left[\frac{e^{-a}-ae^{-1}}2\right]\\
&=\pi\left[e^{-a}-ae^{-1}-\frac{a^2-3a+2}2\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm almost certain that the integral using $f(z)$ does not blow up along the small semicircle about the origin as the semicircle shrinks. It would if the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at the origin had $\frac{1}{z^{2n}}$ terms, but it doesn't.  For geometrical reasons the integral remains finite.  That was the point of my answer.  Furthermore, $\text{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{3}} \ dx = 0$. But your statement implies that the Cauchy principal value of that integral is not finite.

Comment: @RandomVariable: the principal value is indeed $0$, but by very precarious cancellation. My point was that the size of the integrand is not balanced by the size of the contour as it is in the case of $1/z$.

Comment: But why is that relevant here? We're dealing with a specific function and a specific contour that satisfy certain conditions.  That was the point of my answer, namely to explain that those conditions were satisfied and because of that changing the function unnecessary.   Your answer states explicitly that we cannot consider $f(z)$ and that doughnut contour because the integral along the small semicircle about the origin blows up as the semicircle shrinks. But that's not true.

Comment: @RandomVariable: I am not saying that your answer is wrong. I just wanted to warn that on small contours, powers of $z$ less than $-1$ blow up faster than the size of the contour shrinks. This is what the addition of $-1+a$ suggested for the problem removes. In the special case of a semicircle centered on $0$, the integral of $z^{-3}$ is cancelled, but still care must be taken. I have made my caveat a bit more precise.

Comment: I knew the reason for introducing the $-1+a$.  I evaluated an integral on here doing something similar. I just wanted to show that you actually didn't need to change the function in this particular case to use that contour. My only gripe now is that the second half of the first section of your answer is now basically just a restatement of the first part of my answer (which was posted 7 hours earlier).  I linked to a question in which I prove the lemma I stated. And Daniel Fischer proves it in the comment section of that question as well.

Comment: @RandomVariable: My answer was not to comment on your answer. I know you understand what the $-1+a$ does. I am not trying to evaluate the integral in the first or second section. The last part of the first section is simply trying to show that care must be taken since the pieces are not well-behaved near the singularity at $0$. Usually the way that small circular arcs are handled is to cancel the small size of the circle against the size of the integrand. The integral broken into exponentials without $-1+a$ does not have this cancellation.

Comment: @RandomVariable: I have credited you in my answer, even though I had not read your answer before your last comment. Your answer goes into more detail about the contributions of the singularities using the half-doughnut contour.

Comment: Thank you.  And I wasn't accusing you of copying a part of my answer.

Comment: @RandomVariable: It is often the case that two approaches to the same result will be similar. In order to be more precise in what I was trying to say (since I believe my prior imprecision was causing problems), I needed to expand the function about $0$ at least to the $1/z$ term. Then to show that I was not indicating that the integral without $-1+a$ would fail (as it seems was being claimed), I needed to add a bit about the cancellation of the integral of $1/z^3$. It was either that or remove the first section, but then my answer would be incomplete.