# Show that $\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\sin^4 x}{x^4}=\frac{\pi} 3$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Show that $$\int^{\infty}_0 \left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^4=\frac{\pi} 3$$

Although I know the integral with the index is $1$ and $2$, I have no idea on this one. Please help.

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390456/laplace-transform-int-0-infty-frac-sin4-xx3-dx).

Comment: Here's an approach that uses Fourier transforms: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318037/prove-int-0-infty-frac-sin4xx4dx-frac-pi3/318039#318039

Comment: Thanks @Ron: This question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/651188/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint:

I think it 's better to go under [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382975/8581)'s light to see what we need here. Moreover, this is a basic fact that $$\sin^4(x)=3/8+(1/8)\cos(4x)-(1/2)\cos(2x)$$

Of course, I am considering a bit complicated way than other post. In fact, we can show that $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\pi/2$$

Comment: You are always so refreshingly humble and respectful of others' work when you make connections and answer!

Comment: See [Rob](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/307837/8581)'s general case.

Comment: @amWhy: The OP wanted to cross an street so Jonas take his hand and they passed the street. While I did it for him after circulating him around the city. :D Thanks

Comment: I like circulate with you around this wonderful city!