# Integrate $ I(t)=\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\sin tx}{x} \right)^n\,\mathrm d x$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

How to integrate the following:
$$
I(t)=\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\sin tx}{x}  \right)^n\,\mathrm d x$$

I tried to using the Laplace transform:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left[I(t)\right]=\int_0^\infty \mathcal L\left[\left( \frac{\sin tx}{x}  \right)^n\right]\,\mathrm d x
\end{align}

but I don't know what to do then.

Comment: First of make a change of variables $u = tx$ to get $I(t) = Ct^{n-1}$ where $C = \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\right)^n{\rm d}u$. You now know the full $t$ dependence of the function and are left with having to evaluate the constant $C$.

Comment: And the the solution is found here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307510/647013