# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^2 dx$ using complex analysis

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I need to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2dx$.

I have started with defining:
$$f(z) = \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2},\quad z\in\mathbb{C}\;.
$$

Then divided it into four contour integrals, just standard stuff:
[image]

$\int_{-R}^{-r} \frac{1-e^{2ix}}{x^2} dx + \int_{r}^{R} \frac{1-e^{2ix}}{x^2} dx + \int_{C_r }^{} \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2} dz+\int_{C_R }^{} \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2} dz$

First two integrals add up to $2\int_{r}^{R} \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2} dx$

Third integral, Laurent series for $\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2} = \frac{-2i}{z} +2 + \frac{4iz}{3} - \frac{2z^2}{3} +... = \frac{-2i}{z} + P(z)$ and $\int_{C_r} P(z) = 0$ as $r \to 0$, so:

$\int \frac{-2i}{z}dz=-\int_0^\pi \frac{2i^2re^({ti})}{re^{ti}}dt = 2\pi$ for $z = re^{ti}$

$\int_{C_R }^{} \frac{1-e^{2iz}}{z^2} dz \leq \frac{2}{R} +\frac{|e^{2xi}|e^{-2y}}{|z^2|} \leq \frac{2+\pi}{R}= 0$ as $R \to \infty$

$2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2} dx + 2\pi = 4\pi$ so my integral is equal to $\pi$, whereas it should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307510/26872)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1-\cos{2x}=2\sin^2{x}$$
You're missing the $\frac{1}{2}$ when you converted to exponential form.

I believe another mistake you made is that the bounds for the line integral of the semi-circle with little radius r should be $\pi$ to $0$ because it should be in the clockwise direction.  You would get $-2\pi$ from that instead of $2 \pi$.  Then, you should use Cauchy's first theorem instead of second because the semi-circle of little radius r avoids the singularity:
$$ 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos{2x}}{x^2} -2\pi=0$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} \; dx= \boxed{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: Is everything fine besides that? @Ty.

Comment: Where did the $4 \pi$ from?  Everything else looks fine.  I'm not the best at complex analysis though.

Comment: $\frac{1-e^{2zi} }{z^2} $ residue.

Comment: Didn't you avoid the residue at $(0,0)$ by using the little r line integral?

Comment: I edited my answer because I think I found another mistake.

Comment: That is correct. This $4\pi$ should be for a contour "including" $(0,0)$, so below $OX.$. You're right.