# The limit of the integral of $\text{sinc}(x)^n$

Tags: integration, limits

I saw this exercise, and I'm wondering what methods could be used to solve it.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\operatorname{sinc}^n\left(x\right)\,
\mathrm{d}x\right]
$$
Any naïve approach I've tried has failed pretty fast, such as splitting $\operatorname{sinc}^{n}\left(x\right)$ to $\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{1}{x^{n}}$ and integrating by parts, so what method would you use to tackle this problem $?$.

Comment: Sinc is Fourier transform of an interval, and integrals of products are convolutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is $\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}$ that $\sqrt{n}\int_0^\infty\sinc^n x\,dx=\int_0^\infty\sinc^n(t/\sqrt{n})\,dt$ tends to $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/6}\,dt=\color{blue}{\sqrt{3\pi/2}}$ as $n\to\infty$, according to [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). This gives the answer for $y=1/2$, and obviously for other values.

Here is a more detailed explanation. Clearly, $$\sqrt{n}\left|\int_\pi^\infty\sinc^n x\,dx\right|\leqslant\sqrt{n}\int_\pi^\infty\frac{dx}{x^n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)\pi^{n-1}}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$ Hence, if the (first) limit exists, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^\infty\sinc^n x\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^\pi\sinc^n x\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi\sqrt{n}}\sinc^n\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\,dt.$$ Since $\sinc x=1-x^2/6+o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sinc^n(t/\sqrt{n})=e^{-t^2/6}$ for fixed $t$.

It remains to exhibit a dominating function for DCT to apply. But $$0\leqslant\sinc x\leqslant 1-x^2/\pi^2\leqslant e^{-x^2/\pi^2}$$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant\pi$ (the middle inequality follows immediately from the [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Infinite_product_expansion) for $\sin x$, and perhaps may be shown an easier way). Thus, $e^{-t^2/\pi^2}$ is a suitable dominating function.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for comments.*

$$I_n=\frac 1{\pi}\int_0^\infty\big[\text{sinc}(x)\big]^n dx$$ generate the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{3},\frac{115}{384},\frac{11}{40
   },\frac{5887}{23040},\frac{151}{630},\frac{259723}{1146880},\frac{15619}{72576},
   \frac{381773117}{1857945600},\cdots\right\}$$ The numerators are sequence $A049330 $ and the denominators are sequence $A049331$ in $OEIS$.

According to Vladimir Reshetnikov
$$I_n=\frac 1 {2^n (n-1)!}\sum _{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} (-1)^k  \binom{n}{k} (n-2 k)^{n-1}$$
It seems that quite decent approximations could be
$$I_n=\sum_{p=1}^q a_p \,n^{-\frac p2}$$ So, for large values of $n$
$$I_n \sim \frac C {\sqrt n} \qquad \text{with} \qquad C \sim 0.6910$$

Making $n=10^m$, some results
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & \sqrt{10^m}\,I_{10^m} \\
 1 & 0.680550247659969 \\
 2 & 0.689951020377500 \\
 3 & 0.690884642683269 \\
 4 & 0.690977934037989 \\
 5 & 0.690987262459421
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

As @metamorphy and @robjohn commented,as we say in French, I reinvented the warm water !

Comment: Found a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307510) with the exact computation you refer to. As my answer shows, your $C$ is equal to $\sqrt{3/(2\pi)}$.

Comment: A derivation of the formula for $I_n$ is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307837).

Comment: @robjohn. It is a pitty that you work has not been quoted in OEIS. The formula I used was given in year 2016. Cheers :-(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I’ll do a little looking. I doubt my 2013 answer is the first place the formula is given. In fact, user26872’s answer was over 5 hours ahead of mine and gives the same formula.

Comment: @robjohn: I see this as Ex. 13 to Ch. I.VI *(The Theory of Residues)* in [W&W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Course_of_Modern_Analysis).

Comment: @metamorphy: I looked that up and the integral is there, but, at least in the third edition, the formula given is incomplete or misleading. It gives $$\frac{\pi m^{n-1}}{2^n.(n-1)!}\left\{n^{n-1}-\frac n1(n-2)^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}(n-4)^{n-1}-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}(n-6)^{n-1}+\dots\right\}$$ where we are using $m=1$.

Comment: I would interpret this elliptical formula as $$\frac{\pi\,m^{n-1}}{2^n(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-2k)^{n-1}\tag1$$ However, for $n\gt0$, $(1)$ is zero.  It is important that the sum is only over $k\lt n/2$. Perhaps this is corrected in the fourth edition; I don't have a copy of that.

Comment: @robjohn: It's the same [here](https://archive.org/details/ACourseOfModernAnalysis/page/n129/mode/2up), so it's not likely to be "corrected". Anyway, I strongly suspect that the authors interpreted it the "right" way ;) So it dates back at least this far.

Comment: I don't doubt the authors interpreted it in the right way. However, if the formula in the book is read by anyone who does not already know the answer, I would suspect they would include all $n+1$ terms in the sum. I understand this is a staple analysis book, but even those might be improved.

Answer (score 2):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307837/13854) I computed that
$$
\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2^n(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-2k)^{n-1}\tag0
$$
However, in this form, it is difficult to discern the asymptotic behavior as $n\to\infty$.

---

**The Fourier Transform and Central Limit Theorem**

$\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}$The Fourier Transform of $\sinc(x)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2ix}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_\gamma\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2iz}e^{-2\pi iz\xi}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag1\\
&=\pi\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^{iz(1-2\pi\xi)}}{z}\right)-\pi\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^{-iz(1+2\pi\xi)}}{z}\right)\tag2\\[3pt]
&=\pi\left[\zeta\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]-\pi\left[\zeta\le-\frac1{2\pi}\right]\tag3\\[6pt]
&=\pi\left[-\frac1{2\pi}\le\zeta\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Since $\widehat{\!fg}=\widehat{\!f}{\ast}\widehat{\vphantom{f}g}$, the Fourier Transform of $\sinc^n(x)$ is the convolution of $n$ copies of $(4)$.

$(4)$ is the PDF for a probability distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac1{12\pi^2}$. The convolution of $n$ copies of this distribution with itself approaches a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{n}{12\pi^2}$, which has the PDF
$$
f_n(\xi)=\sqrt{\frac{6\pi}n}\,e^{-6\pi^2\xi^2/n}\tag5
$$
Because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\widehat{\!f}(0)$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sinc^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\sim f_n(0)=\sqrt{\frac{6\pi}n}\tag6
$$
and therefore, since $\sinc(x)$ is even,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^\infty\sinc^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}2}}\tag7
$$

---

**Real Approach**

Using $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3819077), it follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1x-\cot(x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2x}{k^2\pi^2-x^2}\tag8\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2x}{k^2\pi^2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2}\right)^j\tag9\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{2\zeta(2j+2)}{\pi^{2j+2}}x^{2j+1}\tag{10}\\
-\log(\sinc(x))
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2j+2)}{\pi^{2j+2}}\frac{x^{2j+2}}{j+1}&&\text{where }|x|\lt\pi\tag{11}\\
\sinc^n\left(x/\sqrt{n}\right)
&=\prod_{j=1}^\infty e^{-\frac{\zeta(2j)}{\pi^{2j}}\frac{x^{2j}}{jn^{j-1}}}&&\text{where }|x|\lt\pi\sqrt{n}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(8)$: apply $\cot(x)=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{k\pi+x}=\frac1x-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2x}{k^2\pi^2-x^2}$
$\phantom{1}(9)$: apply the sum of a geometric series
$(10)$: change the order of summation
$(11)$: integrate
$(12)$: exponentiate

Thus, $(12)$ shows that $\sinc^n\left(x/\sqrt{n}\right)\left[|x|\lt\pi\sqrt{n}\right]$ increases to $e^{-x^2/6}$.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_{\pi\sqrt{n}}^\infty\sinc^n\left(x/\sqrt{n}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|
&\le\int_{\pi\sqrt{n}}^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}x\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{13}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)\pi^{n-1}}\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$
The Monotone Convergence Theorem, $(12)$, and $(14)$ show that
$$
\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\int_0^\infty\sinc^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\sinc^n\left(x/\sqrt{n}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{15}\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/6}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{16}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sqrt{\frac{3\pi}2}}\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{sinc}\pars{x}^{n}\,\dd x}}:
\ {\Large ?}}$. Note that the integrand main contribution comes from values of $\ds{x \gtrsim 0}$ because $\ds{\verts{\on{sinc}\pars{x}} \leq 1}$ and
$\ds{\on{sinc}\pars{0} = 1}$. That suggests the use of [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). Namely,

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\on{sinc}\pars{x}^{n}\,\dd x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{\on{sinc}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 - {x^{2} \over 6}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
n^{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-{nx^{2} \over 6}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{3\pi \over 2}
\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{y - 1/2}\,\,
=
\bbx{\left\{\begin{array}{lclcl}
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{y} & \ds{<} & \ds{1 \over 2}
\\
\ds{\root{3\pi \over 2}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{y} & \ds{=} & \ds{1 \over 2}
\\
\ds{\infty} & \mbox{if} & \ds{y} & \ds{>} &
\ds{1 \over 2}
\end{array}\right.} \\ &
\end{align}

---

It's interesting to note that
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{\on{sinc}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\, &\
\root{3\pi \over 2}\pars{{1 \over n^{1/2}} -
{3 \over 20}\,{1 \over n^{3/2}}}
\end{align}

Comment: I had a look at the question statement and immediately started doing this ... (+1)